# MySQLi error on select query with where field='string'

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I just moved to mySQL 8 and have errors on queries that worked in mySQL 5 before.

I can get the query to work without the string matching part, where it just matches an interger field, but it errors when I add the string part.

Query: `select * from crew where webvisible = 1 and active = 1 and rank = 'member'`

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'member'' at line 1

I need to query based on the rank field where it is different string values like: member or member applicant, or stowaway, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rank` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL 8+. You need to enclose it in backticks i.e.

```
select * from crew where webvisible = 1 and active = 1 and `rank` = 'member'
```